# TensorFlow 1.0 does not see GPU on Windows (but Theano does)

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, gpu, keras

I have a running installation of Keras & Theano on Windows (by following this [tutorial](https://github.com/philferriere/dlwin)). Now I've tried to switch the backend to [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) which worked quite fine.

The only issue I have, is that [Tensorflow does not detect my GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559755/how-to-get-current-available-gpus-in-tensorflow), which Theano in contrast does:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
def get_available_gpus():
    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    return [x.name for x in local_device_protos if x.device_type == 'GPU']
```

yields no results but when running with Theano backend, it works quite nicely:

```
C:\Programming\Anaconda3\python.exe D:/cnn_classify_cifar10.py 
Using Theano backend.
DEBUG: nvcc STDOUT nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
mod.cu
    Creating library C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.5.2-64/tmpgsy496fe/m91973e5c136ea49268a916ff971b7377.lib and object C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.5.2-64/tmpgsy496fe/m91973e5c136ea49268a916ff971b7377.exp

Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 770 (CNMeM is enabled with initial size: 80.0% of memory, cuDNN 5005)
```

Apparently there is some configuration missing, but I don't know what. For Theano to run correctly, I needed a file called `~/.theanorc` with the following content:

```
[global]
device = gpu
floatX = float32

[cuda]
root = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0

[nvcc]
flags=-LC:C:\Programming\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2.amd64\libs
```

Maybe something similar is missing or maybe I need to [add environment variables like for Theano?](https://github.com/philferriere/dlwin#switching-between-cpu-and-gpu-mode). Possibly [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659047/where-is-the-configure-of-tensorflow-and-how-to-enable-the-gpu-support) on Linux (?).

The full installation log (which included a strange exception) can be found in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/apacha/a595c244f90a27aced56f67f7598d90d).

Any ideas, how to make the GPU visible to Tensorflow?

Comment: How did you install tensorflow?

Comment: See my [gist file](https://gist.github.com/apacha/a595c244f90a27aced56f67f7598d90d), using pip install tensorflow and alternatively with the direct url to the wheel.

Comment: The command is wrong.  You need to do pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu

Comment: Nope, see this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/apacha/c51ddc00d9c550a68b1208b0a8d7d424). And why should it? I don't have any Python 2.x installation on my machine.

Comment: My issue wasn't with using pip vs pip3 it was with using tensorflow vs tensorflow-gpu.  I'm not sure the order of precedence if both are installed on your computer.  I think you should uninstall tensorflow and only have installed tensorflow-gpu.

Comment: Right! That fixed it. Write an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I think the provided answer is correct, please accept for more visibility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu on the same machine might cause issues at the moment.

Install either tensorflow (for cpu only) or tensorflow-gpu (for gpu only) for version 1.0

Comment: Huh! It took more googling to find this answer. They seem to overwrite some `pyd` files without any complaints. Why is this little fact not documented? One thinks tensorflow-gpu is an addition to tensorflow and not a substitute.

Comment: I don't have a good answer for why they made it so you can't just install both at the moment or even why their documentation is poor.  I tried a pull request before about documentation (about something) but after months I just closed it because the actual functionality was going to change in a later version.